# Creating a financially feasible Land Title blockchain

Tags: blockchain-interoperation, erc-721

**The Project:**

A block of land, subdivided into several hundred thousand parcels that needs publicly verifiable tracking of current ownership.

While I do have a particular project I'm working with, I will keep the numbers generic.

For our example, let's say each parcel has a real-world value of $100 USD and there are 100,000 parcels available to put into this project (several thousand parcels have been successfully sold/traded over the last 10 years, so we know the land and project is profitable and sustainable).

The current model provides titles as printed documents which are then physically exchanged and ownership transferred through signature lists on each document - so proof of ownership is more of a 'who has possession of the document' than anything....  This makes them both cumbersome to handle and prone to non-authorized duplication (as well as a physical pain to sign when you are transferring 10,000 parcels!).

**The Desire:**

1. Track ownership of the parcel(s).
2. Not require a lot of maintenance internally (self maintainable for future transactions - no central
   reporting agency, etc.)
3. Be SIMPLE to move dozens, hundreds and even
   thousands of titles at a time
4. Be moderately inexpensive to transfer title(s) (preferably < $3 USD for individual parcels, much less for bulk transfers - ideally something like $50 USD as a max fee would be great)
5. Transfer fees can be paid by buyer or seller
6. Transfer fees should be paid from a separate account (i.e., not the one that holds the Title) - NO VALUE should be left in the Title account.
7. Transfer value amounts should be $0 USD (i.e., not set the purchase value to a coin based value - allowing parcels to be used for trade of other items/services/coins/etc.  All value tracking is outside the scope of this project and the responsibility of the parties involved.  The account record is for TITLE, not value.)
8. Be available "forever", with the possibility of 0-100,000 transfers at any point in time (which makes running private resources cost prohibitive)
9. Provide anyone access to publicly view the current owner of record
10. Provide a mechanism for the owner to print a 'suitable for framing' document, should they so desire.
11. Provide a small amount per transaction to cover taxes and such (may go to more than one account)

Blockchain seems to be the right answer in many ways (hands-off, reliable tracking) and I've seen lots of 'speculation' about how blockchain could be used by Title Companies, etc., though I haven't seen any specifics on how to put it together.

**The Challenge:**

While the blockchain does seem like the right answer, there is a large concern about the record being available 'forever' - which is why I am looking for established, reliable blockchain that is mined regularly and will continue to be so (for all foreseeable future...)

*Private Blockchain*

Doing this in a private blockchain seems like a great answer, though with minimal (and unpredictable timeline) transactions, the cost of mining (as well as the project being unlikely to ever have more than one miner) would be extremely high, and therefore, more likely to lend itself to a central-server/database system (which would be simple enough to put together, though require 'forever' maintenance...)

*Public Blockchain*

Much more desirable in the fact that miners are established and plentiful (keeping reliability high) - with Ethereum being the top (and currently only one I know of) choice for long-term tracking.

The problem, though, is that, if we put each parcel in an account, the transaction fees to get started would be astronomical.

We could put large blocks in any given account, and then split it down (transfer into multiple accounts as needed), though tracking the owner of any given parcel at any given time seems extremely difficult (we have no simple way to say "Yes, X owns that parcel and so your document must be fake").

The parties involved are not overly-sophisticated computer geeks so the SIMPLE interface for them to transfer hundreds or thousands of parcels at a time is critical for this to be a viable solution.

**The Questions**

1. How to input each parcel to keep both ease of tracking (by lot/parcel number) and reasonable fees?
2. How to move (using 'publicly available' software/resources) large amounts of parcels at a time?
3. How to pay fees from a separate account (child-pays-for-parent?) where we don't have to load fees on top of the account to cover miner's fees, etc. due to the probable changing of fee rates in the future?
4. Is there a way to achieve all the 'Desired' goals?

I can see how all this is possible with a private blockchain, contracts, mining servers and wallets specifically designed to handle the bulk transactions, though going that direction is just not financially reasonable (due to cost of mining as well as all the development for multiple apps, etc.), so I'm looking for alternative ideas/suggestions.

Comment: Interesting, but the stackexchange mods will not let you keep such a broad question open. It is more suitable for a forum type website. I would be interested in following your project if you can share a link before your question is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This definitely fits into the NFT category (ERC-721). It's not a finalized standard, but it essentially allows for tokens that are treated as separate entities. Instead of owning "3 tokens of the type OMG", you own "Token A, Token B, and Token C of the type PARCEL". They can have their own metadata associated with them as well. Since I assume the metadata associated with a parcel of land could become fairly large, I would suggest storing the metadata in IPFS and storing the IPFS hash in the metadata. This is actually the suggested way to do it anyway on the official [ERC page](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/721).
2. A custom function transferAll can be implemented that just transfers multiple parcels. At **current** gas prices (at 21 gwei), a transfer of 1 parcel will be around $0.50-$0.60, and a transfer of multiple parcels will add a further $0.10-$0.15 per parcel.
3. You could have a custom function `transferFromWithSignature(address to, address from, uint parcelId, bytes signature)`. The owner of a parcel would sign a message containing `from`, `parcelId`, and `beneficiary` (the person to call the function) parameters. The function would verify signature is signed by `from`, the `msg.sender` is the `beneficiary`, and `from` owns `parcelId`. It would then transfer ownership of the parcel to `to` address.
4. Smart contracts are a very diverse tool. The only issue would be the price of bulk transfers, as you can't really cap the cost. It will cost depending on how many parcels are being transferred, as the owner will need to be updated (state updates are expensive compared to other operations) for each parcel.

Edit: Adding additional answers for questions/concerns

**Question**: On the metadata going to IPFS, I have considered it, though what would go there? A picture of the title seems right (Desire #10), though with IPFS anyone could print the title for themselves.... (I have considered a generic 'This is worthless' sort of Certificate, though something more presentable and perhaps personalized would be better, if possible)

**Answer**: You would put any data in IPFS that is needed to know about the parcel. The blockchain would just store the parcelId and the IPFS hash. IPFS would likely store a json document containing info such as name of propety, coordinates and bounds of property. IPFS wouldn't store the title, the title would be the owner of the ERC-721 on the blockchain. There wouldn't really be a way to verify ownership without access to the blockchain. You could generate some kind of image based on this data off-chain, but it would only be for use experience.

**Questions**: I'm concerned (as the title states) about the ~$10,000(+) USD up-front fees ($0 for dev!) - it likely will be a deal breaker...

**Answer**: Instead of creating all ~100,000 parcels on chain at creation time, the creator of the contract could include a function `claimLand(uint parcelId, bytes IPFSHash, bytes signature)` that is signed by the group that creates the whole system. You would sign the parcelId and IPFS hash of each parcel and hand them out to people, and people would claim the land by submitting the IPFSHash and the signature of the hash. The function would verify the signature and create the parcel in the ERC-721 contract. You could also have a function `claimMultipleLands(uint[] parcelId, bytes[] IPFSHash, bytes[] signature)` that does the same for multiple parcels/signatures.

Comment: Thank you for the ERC-721 reference - very interesting, and looks like the spec to watch.  On the metadata going to IPFS, I have considered it, though what would go there?  A picture of the title seems right (Desire #10), though with IPFS anyone could print the title for themselves.... (I have considered a generic 'This is worthless' sort of Certificate, though something more presentable and perhaps personalized would be better, if possible).  Though 721 seems great, I'm concerned (as the title states) about the ~$10,000(+) USD up-front fees ($0 for dev!) - it likely will be a deal breaker...

Comment: See my edit for answers to your additional questions/concerns.

Comment: Interesting! IPFS - clear.  Fees - I thought the contract goes on each account/parcel - guess I need to read up on how all that works (and signature, too - don't know that at all...).  Certainly if we can do claimLand() with fees at claim time (plus a minor set-up, I'm sure), that puts this project on the board.  Recommended reading/next step? Hints on set up/test? (I have 1000 lots I can play with) - I've been programming since 1978, and got excited again when I decided to study blockchain (wish I'd investigated when I heard about it years ago!) - now I need to set it up and do projects!

Comment: Blockchain definitely enables some insane stuff. You only need 1 contract to implement tokens (both erc20 and the  erc721). An erc721 contract basically just contains a mapping of parcelId=> IPFSHash for the data, and a mapping of parcelId => owner for ownership. The contract then has functions like transfer that are only allowed to be called by the owner of the token and it just updates the owner. I would start by learning how to use Truffle (smart contract dev framework) and Ganache (local test network). Also check out OpenZeppelin, which has basic implementations of contracts like erc721.

Comment: Forgive my impatience (I am working through the recommended tasks, though it is slow going due to other tasks) - I have one 'key' thing to clarify (that I haven't found on searching).  Can the origination contract specify the contract for the purchaser(s) 'forever'? I.e., because you purchased a parcel from this contract, when you sell, you must also abide by the 'additional fee' (Desire #11) which will pass dust back to the original owner (who, in this case, due to an original contract, is responsible for taxes) - or, does it just revert to 'contractless' on transfer? Thanks for the help!